# Type issue with Iterator collect

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to convert a vector of `&str` pairs into a `HashMap` with the following code snippet:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
  let pairs = vec!(("foo", "bar"), ("toto", "tata"));
  let map: HashMap<&str, &str> = pairs.iter().collect();
  println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

However the compilation fails with this error:

```
<anon>:5:47: 5:56 error: the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` is not implemented for the type `std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<&str, &str>` [E0277]
<anon>:5   let map: HashMap<&str, &str> = pairs.iter().collect();
```

However if I add `.cloned()` before calling `collect()` everything works fine:

```
...
let map: HashMap<&str, &str> = pairs.iter().cloned().collect();
...
```

Even if I understand the error message (there is no implementation of the trait `FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` for the type `HashMap<&str, &str>`) I do not understand where the type `&(&str, &str)` comes from (according to the method signature in the Rust documentation) and why calling `cloned()` fixes that problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The type `&(&str, &str)` comes from what [`iter()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) on a `Vec` returns:

```
fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>
```

where [`Iter<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) implements `Iterator<Item=&T>`:

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T
    ...
}
```

In other words, `iter()` on a vector returns an iterator yielding references into the vector.

`cloned()` solves the problem because it is an iterator adapter which converts `Iterator<Item=&T>` to `Iterator<Item=T>` if `T` is cloneable. You can think of it as a shorthand for `map(|v| v.clone())`:

```
let v1: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let v2: Vec<_> = v1.iter().cloned().collect();
let v3: Vec<_> = v1.iter().map(|v| v.clone()).collect();
assert_eq!(v2, v3);
```

It happens that `(&str, &str)` is cloneable because each tuple component is also cloneable (all references are), so `cloned()` would return an object which implements `Iterator<Item=(&str, &str)>` - exactly what `collect()` needs to create a `HashMap`.

Alternatively, you can use `into_iter()` to get `Iterator<Item=T>` from `Vec<T>`, but then the original vector will be consumed:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let pairs = vec!(("foo", "bar"), ("toto", "tata"));
    let map: HashMap<&str, &str> = pairs.into_iter().collect();
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that while the references may be copied, the tuples cannot.

However, if you don't need the pairs anymore, you can iterate by values:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
  let pairs = vec!(("foo", "bar"), ("toto", "tata"));
  let map: HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> = pairs.into_iter().collect();
  println!("{:?}", map);
}
```