# Why am I getting double reference to type when iterating over vector of references?

Tags: vector, rust, reference, hashmap, iterator

Consider following minimum reproducible. I have a vector of objects and I have a hashmap where each value is a vector of references to objects from the `objects` vector.

I then get a value from HashMap (which is a reference to vector of references) and I want to filter it so I get vector of references to objects. However, when I do iter-filter-collect, compiler claims that I am iterating over &&O (instead of &O I expect) and errors out.

I can "fix" that error by uncommenting the `map` function which dereferences iterated objects, however I don't think that is the correct thing to do here.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct O {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut objects = vec![
        O { a: 1, b: 0 },
        O { a: 2, b: 0 },
        O { a: 3, b: 0 },
        O { a: 4, b: 1 },
    ];

    let mut b_to_o: HashMap<i32, Vec<&O>> = HashMap::new();
    for o in &objects {
        b_to_o.entry(o.b).or_insert(Vec::new()).push(&o);
    }

    let b_zero: &Vec<&O> = b_to_o.get(&0).unwrap();
    let b_zero_a_odd: Vec<&O> = b_zero
        .iter()
        .filter(|o| o.a % 2 == 0)
        //.map(|o| *o)
        .collect::<Vec<&O>>();
}
```

NOTE: Vector of objects doesn't have to be `mut` in this example, but it has to be in the code I am reproducing.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354947/type-issue-with-iterator-collect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745873/iterator-collect-issue-with-value-of-type-vecstring-cannot-be-built-from-it

Answer (score 3):

You have a `Vec<&T>` and `iter` yields `&Output`, where `Output` is the inner type of the `Vec`, in this case `&T`, you you get: `&Output` => `&&T`.

There is nothing wrong on dereferencing the double reference, you can use map, or you can use `filter_map` as a single step (notice the pattern mathing in the closure parameter to dereference directly `|&o|`):

```rust
let b_zero_a_odd: Vec<&O> = b_zero
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|&o| if o.a % 2 == 0 { Some(o) } else { None })
    .collect::<Vec<&O>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c75fd7d7efecd0de2c7156d1adda174)